# Trying to understand a code phrase from a tutorial

Tags: scripting

I'm an artist eager to understand something of Python for Blender, I've had some lessons of Python in the past, and been studying really hard, watching a lot of tutorials over and over about bpy. There is a piece of code that I didn't get why is it formatted like that:

```
tree = bpy.data.materials.new(name='neon').node_tree

emiss_node = tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeEmission')

data_path = f'nodes["{emiss_node.name}"].inputs[1].default_value'

fcurves = tree.animation_data.action.fcurves

fc = fcurve.find(data_path)
```

The part about `data_path = f'nodes ["{emiss_nod...` Why is the content after 'f' formatted like that? The bracketed content suppose to be what in relation to 'nodes'??

Comment: Hello ! It's because animation drivers are evaluated using a python expression, not the evaluated result of the python expression. So you compare the character string composing the driver expression, not the value of the evaluated expression. Please elaborate if you don't find this clear :) `nodes` is a glorified dictionary of a node tree where each node in the tree is a key in this dictionary, and the value is the node construct. This is the syntax to evaluate a key in a dictionary

Comment: Do you know what an f-string is, in Python?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers! Oh I see now! But not familiar with that therm "glorified dictionary", what does it mean?

Comment: It's not a real Python `dict`, but it implements some aspects of it.

Answer (score 0):

```py
tree = bpy.data.materials.new(name='neon').node_tree
```

Materials created by default don't have a node tree. Therefore `tree` should be `None`, though that may depend on Blender version. A safer way, I think, is:

```py
material = bpy.data.materials.new(name='neon').node_tree
material.use_nodes = True
tree = material.node_tree
```

The snippet shows the material is newly created, therefore it's reasonable to assume the emission node being created is the first emission node and so its name is the default `"emission"`, so the line of interest…

```py
data_path = f'nodes["{emiss_node.name}"].inputs[1].default_value'
```

Evaluates the string to `'nodes["emission"].inputs[1].default_value'`, so under the assumption, the below line should have the same effect:

```py
data_path = 'nodes["emission"].inputs[1].default_value'
```

(notice dropped `f` before the string quote)

Repeating the Martynas' link, because comments may disappear in future:

[Formatted String Literals](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals)

Comment: I see. The context of this code is the creation of a material. The node tree have been created by the code already and the intension of an 'f' quote is to assume the node can have it's name changed. Is that a correct thought?

Comment: @AAAYerus the intention of the f-string is to avoid lengthy and less readable `'nodes["{}"].inputs[1].default_value'.format(emiss_node.name)` syntax, or even worse `'nodes["' + emiss_node.name + '"].inputs[1].default_value'`